# Select all projects from last week - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have an interesting SQL question. I am use to date formats, regular ones, not: `1286229819` which is an actual date in the database. So How do I use this date format to say "select me all projects from last week"?

**Database**: Mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM projects 
WHERE project_date BETWEEN NOW() 
AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Its Day Not Days - I tried to edit but it wont let me so ...

Comment: i just wrote it from memory sorry for that typo